# How to print the repo file hierarchy in github Actions?

Tags: bash, github-actions

Disclaimer: I am 100% new to github Actions and just trying to print a file structure of main branch using "ls -R".

GitHub disabled the old syntax for security reasons.
So i cant seem to use "ls -R" to print all the directories anymore...

This is what i am using right now:
`

```
name: iOS list files workflow

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  job1:
    name: Just print all files
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - id: run_tests
        run: 
          echo "test=$(ls -R)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: dumping
        run:
          echo ${{steps.run_tests.outputs.test}}
```

`

But this is what my output looks like:
`

```
2s
Run echo "test=$(ls -R)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  echo "test=$(ls -R)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
0s
Run echo 
  echo 
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
```

`

As per the previous SO posts, its apparent that githubActions doesn't allow straightaway "ls -R" for printing, so I have to add it to an environment variable for printing.
But the environment variable prints nothing.
If i change `test=$(ls -R)` to `test=hello`,
it does print `hello` on the githubActions log.